# How to Set repeatInterval for 24 hours using SimpleTriggerFactoryBean using XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, job-scheduling, quartz

This is `XML` Configuration file

```
<bean id="orderDetailsJobMonitorRefreshTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="refreshOrderDetailsJobMonitorSchedular"/>
        <property name="startDelay" value="70000"/>
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="200000"/>//How to Set for 24 hours using simple way
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the Quartz doc , `repeatInterval` is the milliseconds. You could use SpEL to call the following static method on `java.time.Duration` to convert a 24 hour to milliseconds:

```java
Duration.ofHours(24).toMillis();
```

In XML, it is equivalent to :

```xml
<property name="repeatInterval" value="#{T(java.time.Duration).ofHours(24).toMillis()}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Pritesh , Glad to hear .So consider to accept my answer or vote it up to give me some encouragement ? 